# Netty encoder pipeline not chaining

Tags: java, sockets, netty, zlib, encoder

Server configuration is:

```
b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
          .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
          .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
              ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
              p.addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(20, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
              p.addLast(new StringDecoder());

              p.addLast(new StringEncoder());
              p.addLast(new JdkZlibEncoder());
              p.addLast(new LengthFieldPrepender(2));
              p.addLast(new MyExecutor());
            }
          });
```

The string encoder is being executed, but I'd have thought the ZLib encoder and the LengthFieldPrepender would be executed? They are not.

My handler content is really simple:

```
@Override
  public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String message) throws Exception {
    if (message.equals("A")) {
      ctx.writeAndFlush("B");
      return;
    }

    if (messageStr.equals("B")) {
      ctx.writeAndFlush("A");
      return;
    }
  }
```

What I receive then is a string: "A", and I send "B", but I want Netty to really send "1 XX", where 1 is the size, and XX is the ZLIB encoded content.

Does that make any sense? Why are encoders not chaining?

Comment: I think this is the problem https://github.com/netty/netty/commit/73755d12330bb0a976c9a32c3fcdc6f39b15249d? This class was `MessageToByteEncoder` now it's `MessageToMessageEncoder`?